# How to compare a string to a array content on javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I compare a String that comes from HTML, with an array and get the position of it?

```
var fruit = ["apple", "banana"];

var $textOfHtml = "apple";
```

The problem is how do I get something like this below:

```
"apple" is on the [0] position?
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array, in particular https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: Use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) or a loop.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggest, you want to use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Using your code, here is the usage:

```
var fruit = ["apple","banana"]
var $textOfHtml = "apple"
var i = fruit.indexOf($textOfHtml)
var str = $textOfHtml + ' is on the [' + i + '] position'
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var fruit = ["apple", "banana"]
var text = "apple"

function compare(array, string, index) {

  var x = []
  var y = array[index]
  x.push(y)
  var z = x.toString().trim()

  if (z == string) {
    return (string + ' is on the ' + index + ' position!')
  }
}
```

.push into an empty array to isolate the array item to run .toString() and then .trim() for good measure does the trick every time

Answer (score 0):

You have to use array indexOf() method to find the positon of your desired value

```
   <body>
        <script>
            var array = ["apple","banana"];
            var text = "banana";

            var position = array.indexOf(text);

            alert(position);
        </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The indexOf() method searches the array for the specified item, and returns its position.

```
var Index = fruit .indexOf($textOfHtml);

alert($textOfHtml+" is on the ["+Index +"] position");
```